# Combining three formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to combine three formulas in one cell but not having much luck, all work in separate cells.

```
=K6/B6
=IF(B6="",0,G6) 
=IF(ISBLANK(B6),0,L6)
```

Comment: What are you trying to check with `B6=""` vs `ISBLANK(B6)`? Also, can you textually describe what you are trying to do with a combined formula?

Comment: Please edit your question with details of which cells the current formulas are in.

Comment: @Sarah Forshaw ,,, currently which version of XL are you using ? Logically 2nd and 3rd formula contradicts each other,,,, since U are testing B6 for BLANK,, if TRUE then 0,,, otherwise once is G6 and next  is L6,,,, !!! Please [edit] the post and modify the question to avoid it to be closed,,,, already it has 4 down votes !!

Answer (score 1):

How about this formula: =K6/IF(ISBLANK(B6),0, IF(B6<>"", L6, IF(B6="",0, G6)))

In general, a cell is blank, must be an empty string, and conversely, not necessarily. So I used continuous nested functions.